# Prepopulate Image field node/add

Tags: nodes, media

Ok, I'm at the end of my rope. I tried the "Prepopulate" module, but wasn't much of help.

I have created a content type where user can upload an image in a field: field_rimage in content type StockImages.

When the user views the image, user can choose an image to prepopulate the image field: field_rimage in a new node of another content type Receipe.

As such,User goes to www.example.com/StockImages/ gets a bunch of images clicks on an image... gets redirected to www.example.com/node/add/Receipe
with the image field in Receipe already containing the image selected without having to reuploaded.

I hope I made sense!
Thanks.